# Microsoft Dynamics eConnect-- allowed to have a negative markdown?

Tags: dynamics-gp

We're using Dynamics GP 2010 and interfacing with it from C#.  We would like to have a negative markdown amount (MRKDNAMT in Dynamics parlance) but we're getting a strange error about the number of invoices being incorrect when we send over eConnect.

Would anyone know whether it's possible to have a negative MRKDNAMT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Dynamics GP 2010 does not allow negative markdown amounts to be entered. You can test this yourself by attempting to enter a negative markdown amount in the Dynamics GP client. If you can't do it in the client, then usually eConnect will not allow you do it either.